# How are MongoDB's ObjectIds generated?

Tags: mongodb

Are they *somewhat* random?

I mean....would people be able to break them apart?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Generation

They are usually generated on the client side by the driver itself. For example, in ruby, BSON::ObjectID can be used:

- https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/master/lib/bson/object_id.rb#L369

You can also generate your own ObjectIds. This is particularly useful if you want to use business identifiers.

### Breakability

- When using driver generated ObjectIds, is low
- When using own business Id, is slightly higher depending on their predictability (login, consecutives identifiers...)

Comment: yes they can be predicted if you have related ObjectIds available for analysis. But I suppose you'll agree it's much more difficult to guess than usual Identity columns in traditional DBs...

Comment: Yes, incremental ids are easier to guess, but Mongo ObjectId can not be considered safe.

Comment: And since they are not random and can be easily broken apart, you can do this for example in the mongo shell: ObjectId().getTimestamp() to know when it was created.

Comment: wouldnt a uuid provide more uniqueness? With this algorithm it does not seem to be impossible to generate duplicate ids... where does the "machine"-id come from?

Answer (score 51):

They are not random and can be easily predicted :

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value
>   consisting of a 4-byte timestamp
>   (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte
>   machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a
>   3-byte counter

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Comment: FYI: The linked documentation no longer agrees with the quoted text -- it mentions a "a 5-byte random value" rather than using "id" values.  So, essentially, there is a 32-bit timestamp concatenated with a 64-bit randomly-initialized counter.  **The conclusion is the same:** _It would be easy to guess additional ObjectId values if you have a valid value from the same system._

Answer (score 21):

Heres a javascript implementation of the MongoDB ObjectID (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/rN3zb/)

```
function ObjectIdDetails (id) {
    return {
        seconds: parseInt(id.slice(0, 8), 16),
        machineIdentifier: parseInt(id.slice(8, 14), 16),
        processId: parseInt(id.slice(14, 18), 16),
        counter: parseInt(id.slice(18, 24), 16)
    };
}
```

So if you have enough of them they leak quite a bit of information about your infrastructure. And you also know the object creation dates for everything.

IE: how many servers do you have, and how many processes each server is running.

Answer (score 11):

MongoDB database drivers by default generate an ObjectID identifier that is assigned to the _id field of each document. In many cases the ObjectID may be used as a unique identifier in an application.

ObjectID is a 96-bit number which is composed as follows:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch (which will not run out of seconds until the year 2106)

a 3-byte machine identifier (usually derived from the MAC address),

a 2-byte process id, and

a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Answer (score 2):

From the MongoDB Official Document [links](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)
it shows :

> ObjectId
>   ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and
>   ordered. ObjectId values consist of 12 bytes, where the first four
>   bytes are a timestamp that reflect the ObjectId’s creation.
>   Specifically:
>
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>     a
>   5-byte random value, and
>     a 3-byte counter, starting with a random
>   value.
>     In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a
>   unique _id field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document
>   omits the _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an
>   ObjectId for the _id field.

Comment: The 5 byte "random value" does not appear to be random. The other answers suggest it is a combination of a Machine identifier and a process id.

Comment: @Jontia  thanks ,  the   5-byte random value  are immutable  when  insert one by one !

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB database drivers by default generate an ObjectID identifier that is assigned to the _id field of each document. In many cases the ObjectID may be used as a unique identifier in an application.](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb)

Total 12 bytes:

- 4-byte timestamp value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch (which will not run out of seconds until the year 2106)
- 5-byte random value, and
- 3-byte incrementing counter, starting with a random value.

Example from mongo-go-driver:

```golang
    var objectId [12]byte

    // 4 bytes unix time-stamp second (big endian)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(objectId[0:4], uint32(timestamp.Unix()))

    // global random number generated by driver 
    copy(objectId[4:9], processUnique[:])
    
    // global counter by driver
    putUint24(objectId[9:12], atomic.AddUint32(&objectIDCounter, 1))
```