# How can I generate an ObjectId with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to generate a MongoDB `ObjectId` with Mongoose. Is there a way to access the `ObjectId` constructor from Mongoose?

- This question is about **generating a new** `ObjectId` from scratch. The generated ID is a brand new universally unique ID.
- Another question asks about creating an `ObjectId` from an **existing string representation**. In this case, you already have a string representation of an ID—it may or may not be universally unique—and you are parsing it into an `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 438, accepted):

You can find the `ObjectId` constructor on `require('mongoose').Types`. Here is an example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

`id` is a newly generated `ObjectId`.

---

**Note**: As [Joshua Sherman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899750/how-can-i-generate-an-objectid-with-mongoose/17899751?noredirect=1#comment122158950_17899751) points out, with Mongoose 6 you must prefix the call with `new`:

```
var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

---

You can read more about the `Types` object at [Mongoose#Types documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids).

Comment: how can you be sure that this is really unique? does mongoose any check before?

Comment: @R01010010 check out how these are generated (Google). There's no check but it's probabilistic

Comment: If you generate 16777216 within one second on the same machine, then you will probably get a duplicate. :)

Comment: Correction: If you generate 16777216 within one millisecond on the same machine, then you will probably get a duplicate. 

Comment: @joeytwiddle what is this number 16777216 ?

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran it's 2^24, supposing you are using 24 bits for the random portion of the ID

Comment: [How are MongoDB's ObjectIds generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817795/how-are-mongodbs-objectids-generated) The local counter is three bytes, or six hex chars. We can calculate: `256 ** 3 === 16 ** 6 === 16777216`

Comment: looks like with mongoose 6 you have to add new  ``new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()``

Answer (score 69):

You can create a new MongoDB `ObjectId` like this using mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var newId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca');
// or leave the id string blank to generate an id with a new hex identifier
var newId2 = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId();
```

Comment: `mongoose.mongo`?

Answer (score 33):

I needed to generate mongodb ids on client side.

After digging into the mongodb source code i found they generate ObjectIDs using npm `bson` lib.

If ever you need only to generate an ObjectID without installing the whole mongodb / mongoose package, you can import the lighter `bson` library :

```
const bson = require('bson');
new bson.ObjectId(); // 5cabe64dcf0d4447fa60f5e2
```

Note: There is also an npm project named `bson-objectid` being even lighter

Comment: The size of "unpacked" `bson` is almost as heavy as `mongodb`.

Answer (score 29):

With ES6 syntax

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// Generate a new new ObjectId
const newId2 = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
// Convert string to ObjectId
const newId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca');
```

Comment: what's the diff between mongoose.Type and mongoose.Schema.Types ?

Comment: mongoose.Schema.Types will be used to within your schema when you want to reference between collections. To create a single objectId within your code use simply mongoose.Types

Comment: @stefano, mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId and mongoose.Types.ObjectId, is the exactly same

Answer (score 1):

The import is mongo from mongoose, the node-mongodb-native driver. If you open the package you can verify !

```
import { mongo } from 'mongoose'
const newId = new mongo.ObjectId()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me in mongoose v8 (+ typescript) was this:

```
const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

console.log(objectId);
```