# Mongoose model keys not being inserted in Postman post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use the post method below to create new documents. But when I send a post request in Postman (e.g. http://localhost:3000/api/posts?title=HeaderThree) a new document is created but the keys and values are missing.

```
router.route('/posts')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Post.find(function(err, posts) {
            if (err) { return res.send(err)}
            res.json(posts)
        })
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        const post = new Post(
            {
                title: req.body.title,
                text: req.body.text
            }
        );

        post.save(function(err, post) {
            if (err) { return res.send(err)};
            res.json({ message: 'Post added!'});
        });
    });
```

The schema is this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema(
    {   
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        title: {type: String},
        text: {type: String },
        comments: {type: Array}
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('PostSchema', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending data as query string:

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/posts?title=HeaderThree
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then you have to use `req.query` to get them from express server:

```
const post = new Post(
    {
        title: req.query.title,
        text: req.query.text
    }
);
```

If you want to send data as form bodies, you need to use [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

...
```

Now you could use `req.body` object to get submitted data.

One last thing, don't forget to populate form data under body tab in postman

Comment: I changed body to queries and now it works perfectly. I must have made a mistake somewhere else though, because I had already included app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
```

in your model  :

```
const PostSchema = new Schema(
    {   
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        title: {type: String},
        text: {type: String },
        comments: {type: Array}
    }
)
```

before you insert the document you have to give it an _id :

_id :  mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

your document will be :

```
const post = new Post(
            {
                _id :  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                title: req.body.title,
                text: req.body.text
            }
        );
```

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899750/how-can-i-generate-an-objectid-with-mongoose)

Comment: I tried this and it returns {
    "message": "document must have an _id before saving",
    "name": "MongooseError"
}

Comment: Now it's going back to what it did before. It creates a document with the default date and an id but doesn't include the req.body values.