# mongoose schema model _id

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose 5.0.9. My question is about the `_id` of document.

I'd like to get `_id generated from mongodb when new document inserted. In this way, I could not define the _id in my mongoose schema/model. If I do, the mongoose will fail since I don't provide the value for _id.

However, I want to use the _id in my page. If I don't define it in my schema/model, I could not get it when querying.

One solution I thought is to define two schemas: one for inserting document without _id, and the other is for querying, updating, etc, with _id.

I don't want to make things to complex, so I don't think this is good idea. 
what is the best practice for this _id?

Thanks in advance.
Richard

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899750/how-can-i-generate-an-objectid-with-mongoose

Comment: Thank you very much. That's all I need.