# How to get id model constructor mockingoose jest

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, jestjs, mockingoose

How to predict _id in jest test using mockingoose

```js
const newUser = new User({
    username: username,
    name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
})
```

how to know what id will `new User()` return

```js
const user = {
    id: 'a'
    username: 'username',
    name: 'Name',
    email: 'email@example.com',
    password: 'password',
}
```

User schema

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

const User = new Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)
```

how to make user same as newUser

Comment: Where is your `User` defined?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899750/how-can-i-generate-an-objectid-with-mongoose