# How to convert a Mongoid _id into a timestamp (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I just read this SO post:

[How are MongoDB's ObjectIds generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817795/how-are-mongodbs-objectids-generated)

According to an answer there MongoDB ID's are not random and can be easily predicted. You can even convert it into a timestamp:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

I was wondering, is it possible to convert an _id (e.g. `52a435840000640002695268` or `52908452636872eda1000000`) into a timestamp using the `mongoid`gem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB IDs are parsed via Mongoid into instances of the class `BSON::ObjectId`, and that class has a method `generation_time` - http://rubydoc.info/gems/bson/2.0.0/BSON/ObjectId:generation_time

This gives you the time that the ID was generated at as a Ruby Time object, which I believe is what you were after.

Comment: The current Mongoid uses Moped so it is actually `Moped::BSON::ObjectId` but there is still a [`generate_time`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/BSON/ObjectId:generation_time) method.

Comment: ah I was looking at Mongoid v2. Good to know it still works though.