# Can I get ObjectID in MongoDB with Python during submission of data form

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm creating a simple recipe blog as milestone for my course where I need to use Python+Flask+MongoDB. I wrote the following code in Python, I'm a student then forgive me if my code is not very good:

```
    @app.route('/insert_recipe', methods=['POST'])
    def insert_recipe():
       recipes = mongo.db.recipes
       recipes.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())

       if request.files:

          image = request.files["picture"]

          path = os.getcwd()
          image_dir = path + "/static/images/" + image.filename
        
          image.save(image_dir)

    # Once that's done, we redirect to recipe.html, so we can view the new recipe in our collection.
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I have a form where I need to submit the entire recipe, and everything works well, all the data go to MongoDB. I'm working in local at the moment, then the image is saved in the local folder. Now what I would like to accomplish, is to rename the image with the new ObjectID created in MongoDB before the redirect. I'm not even sure this is possible. I thought I could get the ObjectID of the last record created in the database, but then I thought that if another user submit a recipe right at that moment, I would save the image with the wrong ID. Is it possible to save the image with the ObjectID value? Like 5f00baf5a475e9cd9a584ae7.jpeg for example.

Thank you in advance, I'm really enjoying Python!

Comment: `recipes.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())` returns you the ObjectId of the document inserted. Use that ObjectId in place of `image.filename`. Please see the returns from the insert_one(). https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one
I would also suggest instead of inserting everything in the DB using `request.form.to_dict()`, do a validation check on inputs, parse the input, create your own input_json, and then insert in  DB `recipes.insert_one(input_json)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! Very helpful.

Comment: you are welcome. Please vote both the comment. It will be helpfull for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code slightly and this should be possible:

```
    @app.route('/insert_recipe', methods=['POST'])
    def insert_recipe():
       recipes = mongo.db.recipes
       doc = request.form.to_dict()
       recipes.insert_one(doc) # when the insert succeeds doc will have an _id field with the object ID

       if request.files:

          image = request.files["picture"]

          path = os.getcwd()
          image_dir = path + "/static/images/" + str(doc["_id"]) + ".jpeg"
        
          image.save(image_dir)

    # Once that's done, we redirect to recipe.html, so we can view the new recipe in our collection.
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

When you insert a doc in MongoDB the object ID is created automatically in the `_id` field. This happens for every new document that is inserted and within a single collection. The object IDs are guaranteed to be unique. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817795/how-are-mongodbs-objectids-generated) on Object IDs.

Comment: Please explain how you get ObjectId in `doc`. Otherwise, it will confuse new/beginner developers and they might get a wrong understanding of the core concepts.

Comment: @Joe @knownUnknown thank you for both the code and the link, they both helped. I solved and I also added a line more since I didn't know the picture extension.

`code
        ext = image.filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1]
        path = os.getcwd()
        image_dir = path + "/static/images/" + str(dict1["_id"]) + "." + ext
`

Comment: Added some additional commentary on object IDs.